# TextPad: how do I stop the beep on Auto Reload

Tags: textpad

Folks,
I love TextPad and have been using it for a long time.  There is one feature that I wish I could stop TextPad from doing.  Does anyone knows how I can stop TextPad from sounding a BEEP everytime it updates a file, when the File Setting is Auto-Reload in the menu: Configure.Preferences?

Many thanks,
Avi

Answer (score 10):

This question is really off topic for StackOverflow, but anyway...  This should work:

Uncheck the "Audible Alerts" setting under `Configure -> Preferences... -> View`